# Different perspective of view in a Display

Tags: color-management, display

I love to shoot raw.  I have a desktop with a 20 inch LG HD LED Monitor, and most of my 
post-processing is done using DPP (Digital Photo Professional). I also have an HP Compaq 15-s001TU Notebook.  I prefer viewing some of my best photographs on my HP Compaq Notebook, but the photographs look brighter, with richer color and with dynamic contrast in my HP notebook. I also calibrated the brightness/contrast setting with the desktop but it didn't help much.  Why is that?  Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean "i also calibrated the Brightens contrast setting with the desk top"? I think your issue is that you haven't properly calibrated both displays.

Answer (score 0):

Every monitor is different, you can't expect any two monitors to display colors the same way unless they are calibrated - and by calibrated I mean you used an hardware device that reads the color from the screen and created a color profile, you can't calibrate a monitor using the monitor's controls.

Note that manufacturers tend to mis-calibrate the monitors to be brighter, more saturated and more contrasty (the things you like about your laptop monitor) because it looks better when compared to other monitors in the store, so, as a wild guess, I would say that your laptop's monitor is very badly calibrated and if you do set it correctly - so it shows colors how they are supposed to look - it will be darker, less saturated and with lower contrast then your desktop monitor (but on the bright side, if you calibrate both monitors, both will display the image not the same but at least with somewhat similar colors and contrast)